# "Heute fragte mich ein Mädchen" oder "Heute fragte ein Mädchen mich"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Welcher Satz ist richtig?

> Heute fragte mich ein Mädchen nach einer Adresse.
>   Heute fragte ein Mädchen mich nach einer Adresse.

Comment: Beide. Und noch einige Varianten mehr. Du könntest höchstens fragen, welche Variante umgangsprachlich häufiger verwendet wird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Als Nachschlagewerk dient hier mal wieder [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Mittelfeld/Subjekt.html?MenuId=Sentence5310).

> 1) Das Subjekt steht im Mittelfeld an erster Stelle.

Beispiel: *Heute fragte [<sub>Sub</sub>das Mädchen] [<sub>Obj</sub>den Vater]...*

Aber:

> 2) [Pronomen vor Nomen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Mittelfeld/Pronomen.html)

Beispiel: *Heute fragte [<sub>Obj</sub>ihn] [<sub>Sub</sub>das Mädchen]...*

Sind beides Pronomen, gilt wieder Regel 1.

Beispiel: *Heute fragte [<sub>Sub</sub>sie] [<sub>Obj</sub>ihn]...*

Comment: Still I would not consider variant 2 as wrong.

Comment: yes, it is uncommon but technically correct.

Comment: -1 because both are versions correct (the canoo-rules don't get it) and because the answer has to be deduced from what's written. If you want to say that only 1) is right, then you should say it. And @christian.s... how is it uncommon? It is very common, actually

Comment: For me, 2 sounds absolutely wrong, but it would be possible without mich ('Heute fragte ein Mädchen nach einer Addresse.') if the context makes clear, that she asked me.

Comment: "Heute nach einer Adresse das Mädchen mich fragte." sounds super-strange to me, but both versions from the OP feel natural to me (Saxony), and I don't think either version puts much emphasis on any word.

Comment: @blutorange Huh? Are you sure you wanted to comment on my answer?

Answer (score 5):

> Das Mädchen fragte mich heute nach einer Adresse.

That is the normal word order. The subject goes before the adverb of time.

> Heute fragte mich das Mädchen nach einer Adresse.

This sentences emphasizes the adverb of time ‘heute’.

> Heute fragte das Mädchen mich nach meiner Adresse.

This is also right because your emphasize is on the object ‘mich’. Carsten is right.

Comment: dankeschön :) the description is so useful

Comment: -1 because it is only the "Normal" word order from an English perspective. I would consider version two much more normal.  Sentence 2 does NOT emphasize "heute".